# Gtk object, name, type and so

Tags: gtk

I Created a window and vbox with 3 buttons in Glade. All buttons have connected "Clicked" event to same handler. Handler looks like this:

```
CLICKED_btn(GtkObject *object, gpointer user_data)
{
    g_print("CLICKED\n");
}
```

CLICKED appears on terminal for any click to any button.
Is here a way, through object or other to know which button invokes event Clicked in case where all buttons uses same handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object` parameter refers to the object that generates the event, in your case the button. Then you can use `gtk_widget_get_name()` or any other GtkObject/GtkWidget/GtkButton function to make a difference.

**UPDATE**:
As it seems, newer versions of GTK/Glade do not set the name of the widgets to their `id`, so it is left to the default, that is the name of the type. In order to get the `id` of the object you can use the function `gtk_buildable_get_name()` that works with any buildable object.

With that you'll get `button1`, `button2` or whatever name you put to these buttons.

Please, do not use the label to make a difference between the buttons. Yes, it works, but it is a bad habit: hard to maintain, bad with internationalization, and defeats the main purpose of Glade: to have the interface and the code separated.

Comment: Thank you for useful tips. Now I have 'code'     char* o_name = gtk_widget_get_name(GTK_WIDGET(object));
    char* btnlab = gtk_button_get_label(GTK_BUTTON(object)); 'code' where o_name is "GtkButton" and btnlab is "button1". I would like to know additionally is here any possibility to cast o_name instead of "GTK_BUTTON" and how this should look like because of getting some ore flexibility in practical programming.

Comment: I am sorry, my english can be weird :) I ask this: with gtk_widget_get_name I get returned "GtkButton" what mean that Gtk find that caller is of GtkButton type. To get label of concrete button I call gtk_button_get_label(GTK_BUTTON(object)); and I get exact label of exact button. Question is why I should write GTK_BUTTON(object) in second call when we already determined that caller object IS GtkButton and can I use here value of o_name variable instead of GTK_BUTTON(object), something like o_name(object). In that case I wouldn't have to know which is the type of caller widget.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. The GTK_BUTTON macro is just a syntactic hack to make C more object oriented. But you must never use a `gtk_button_*()` function with anything but a `GtkButton`. Please, see the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, thank you for additional explanations and great help in my learning of Gtk. const char* bname = gtk_buildable_get_name(GTK_BUILDABLE(object)); works excellent, just as expected! I will try to remember useful advices.

Answer (score 0):

First use the documentation to have the right prototype for the ["clicked" signal](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-clicked) of a GtkButton.

You then know that your callback's prototype should look like:

`void on_button_cliked (GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)`

The `button` parameter is the object which received the signal, ie. the button on which you clicked.

Comment: Yes, you are right for this case but there are possibility to pass different type of widgets (objects) to same handler.